# AngularJS, filters: how to turn a big giant object (JSON) into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I'm having some issues with the Angular filters, according to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) the filter only works with arrays, I have now a very big object, is actually to display some dynamic content. I will leave you guys some different examples of what I am going through.

1st the behavior I want to achieve, [you can see it here](http://plnkr.co/edit/su8CD9L01XMXowCkXcel?p=preview).

2nd let's say that [this is](http://plnkr.co/edit/2Z5SMlANCGd3r4Trfwzm?p=preview) with the real JSON object that just extract from Network in my browser console.

In the second example you verify why my searcher is not working, is actually because of the object I just mentioned above.

I have service named `SportsFactory` with this function

```
$http.get(CONSTANT_VARS.BACKEND_URL + '/lines/sports/' + agent)
            .success(function(sports) {
              //here I need: forcing array instead of object
              sports = _.values(sports);
              sports = _.sortBy(sports, function(sport) {
                return sport.priority;
              });
              console.log(sports)
              LocalForageFactory.set(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS, sports);
              defer.resolve(sports);
            })
            .error(function(err) {
              defer.reject(err);
            });
```

as you can see there is a `console.log` which is returning this:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

now, what can I do in order to have my filters working correctly?
What can I do in order to convert that `sports object` into an array?

basically this part of the function is the one returning that object I told you, which is the one that I need to return an Array instead

```
      .success(function(sports) {
          //forcing array instead of object
          sports = _.values(sports);
          sports = _.sortBy(sports, function(sport) {
            return sport.priority;
          });
          console.log(sports)
          LocalForageFactory.set(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS, sports);
          defer.resolve(sports);
        })
```

Comment: that sports object is already an Array of objects and if any of the properties of these objects are strings, Angular filter will match against them. Can you clarify what is the problem and maybe provide an example plunker

Comment: @VladimirGurovich yes, [this is the example](http://plnkr.co/edit/2Z5SMlANCGd3r4Trfwzm?p=preview), just see the example and try to type something on the search box, it is now working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a plunkr with the filter working, I just set the array you were making equal to a $scope.variable and used that for the ng-repeat.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/QxSaWmKhEOymXECeUtRW?p=preview)

I altered the code a bit since I wasn't doing the GET request in the plunkr but the idea is the same.

```
var mySports = _.values($scope.sports);
    $scope.sportsArray = _.sortBy(mySports, function(sport) {
    return sport.priority;
});
console.log($scope.sportsArray);

//and the HTML

<div ng-repeat="sport in sportsArray | filter:query"></div>
```

Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: but this code is for a service. Angular says you should not use $scope in service.

Comment: If the array is being built in a Service return a value, and in your controller set the $scope value equal to Service.returnedValue.